# Why does my push function store my data in a nested manner?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I am working on updating my **localStorage** to store specific data after every transaction made by the client user. I noticed that my code saves the data in a **nested** format. This is not desirable.

What would be desirable is if the data is stored in un-nested format.

Find attached descriptive images, to give you a clearer idea of what I mean.

[image: An image of the data saved in array format]

[image: An image the nested arrays]

How do I formulate my code to save these data in **NON** nested manner?

Find below my code

```
var newData = {}; var transactionDataRetrieved = [];
newData.TransactionTime= "Thu 20:11",
newData.amount= "15,000",
newData.payersNumber= "070505788",
newData.transactionNumber= "PSC999",
newData.waitersName= "Agnes Johnsson!"

transactionDataRetrieved.push({newData: newData}); 

transactionDataRetrieved.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData')));
localStorage.setItem('transactionData', JSON.stringify(transactionDataRetrieved));
```

Comment: Do you want your newest data at the beginning or the end of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing the old value onto a new array every time and then saving it back.  Here's one (untested) alternative, adding the newest data to the end.  It wouldn't be hard to modify it to put that data at the beginning.

```js
var transactionDataRetrieved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData') || '[]');
var newData = {}; 
newData.TransactionTime = "Thu 20:11",
// ...

transactionDataRetrieved.push(newData);

localStorage.setItem('transactionData', JSON.stringify(transactionDataRetrieved));
```

Or in a single expression:

```js
localStorage .setItem ('transactionData', JSON .stringify (
    (JSON.parse (localStorage .getItem ('transactionData') || '[]') .concat (newData)
))
```

Comment: Sorry, but why we using es6 feature here?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: First of all, why not?  But secondly, which features are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, it was there in a comment temporarily.  But I've taken to embracing es6 everywhere, using Babel or such to compile as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing array to array

```
// pushing object to array
transactionDataRetrieved.push({newData: newData}); 

// pushing array to array
// localStorage.getItem('transactionData') returns array
// because you created, var transactionDataRetrieved = []; as array
transactionDataRetrieved.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData')));
localStorage.setItem('transactionData', JSON.stringify(transactionDataRetrieved));
```

What you should be doing

```
transactionDataRetrieved.push({newData: newData}); 

// changed push to concat
var newArray = transactionDataRetrieved.concat(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData')));
localStorage.setItem('transactionData', JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor issues with your code that I want edit check it:

```
var newData = {}; 
newData.TransactionTime= "Thu 20:11",
newData.amount= "15,000",
newData.payersNumber= "070505788",
newData.transactionNumber= "PSC999",
newData.waitersName= "Agnes Johnsson!"
// **newData** is already an Object so don't wrap it in an object
//First get data from the localStorage;
//store it in array of Objects
var transactionDataRetrieved = localStorage.getItem('transactionData');
transactionDataRetrieved.push(newData); 
//Now set this array in local storage
localStorage.setItem('transactionData', transactionDataRetrieved);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, your solution returns this error: `Uncaught TypeError: transactionDataRetrieveds.push is not a function`